# Preparing & Binding

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I'm a relative (complete) newbie (horrible word) when it comes to PHP and SQL. I fear I have stumbled into a deep-end scenario. I'm trying to get my head around binding/prepared statements.

Here is my code:

```
require('connect.inc.php')

if (isset($_GET['first_name']) && !empty($_GET['first_name'])) {
    $first_name = trim($_GET['first_name']);
    $query = "SELECT first_name, second_name FROM join_names WHERE first_name=?";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);

    if($query_prepared = mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $first_name);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $fn, $sn);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        echo $fn.' '.$sn;
    }
}
```

Now the code works. It presents the first name, and second name of the value entered in $_GET. I have very little idea how or why but I think I've narrowed that down.

The main problem I'm having understanding this starts with mysqli_stmt_init. What is it? How are parameters bound to it without the need for a variable to anchor it down? Clarification here: you start with $stmt from mysqli_stmt_init, then you prepare it, then you bind parameters to it, then it is executed. How do all these changes stick?

The second query is, what exactly does stmt_prepare do? I get that it prepares the statement (in theory I know that, but in practice I have zero idea what that means).

On both of these I've looked at definitions and manuals and absolutely nothing is clicking. PHP.net is a complete mess of jargon to me that, as of right now, I just don't have the knowledge to understand.

I'm sorry this must be so clear to everyone here but for me its just not hitting home. Regardless, thank-you for any help you can provide :)

Comment: See: [Use the Index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters)

Comment: Way above my current level of understanding, but thank-you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer one point at a time:

> The main problem I'm having understanding this starts with mysqli_stmt_init. What is it?

from the refman:

> mysqli_stmt_init — Initializes a statement and returns an object for
>   use with mysqli_stmt_prepare

Basically, it's just the starting point. The OOP approach is easier to understand, in my opinion. Give it a try.

Next question:

> How are parameters bound to it without the need for a variable to anchor it down?

When you prepare a statement, the querystring (with the placeholders for the actual values) is parsed, and the placeholders are discovered and identified.
These informations are stored in an object, which waits for your correct values to execute the query with. In the meantime, that object talks with the database and prepares your query execution plan.

Now you have prepared a statement. A prepared statement at this point is basically the following:

- A query execution plan;
- A list of placeholders awaiting your values to actually execute the query with.

When you bind a parameter to the statement, it will get paired with the first available placeholder. Once you've bound every placeholder, you can execute the statement.

What happens now? The execution isn't simply a string replacement with the values in place of the "question marks". The statement object tells the database "Hey, can you please run the plan we agreed 5 seconds ago, using these values I have now?" (this subtle difference is why sql injection with prepared statement is basically impossible).

So, to recap:

- `mysqli_stmt_init` is the starting point.
- `mysqli_stmt_prepare(stmt, query)` will create one execution plan in the DB engine, and identifies the parameters placeholders you requested.
- `mysqli_stmt_bind_param(stmt, value_type, value)` assigns one value to the first available placeholder
- `mysqli_stmt_execute(stmt)` will make the DB execute the query plan decided above, with the values received from the bound parameters.

Comment: Thank-you very much. I'll go over what you've said and see how it pans out. Also I see the OO approach is probably easier, but I've been self teaching and started with procedural. I aim to get my tentative grasp on procedural before starting on OO, otherwise I'll just confuse myself further.

Comment: I see your point @RussellKitchen but don't postpone OOP too much. That's the modern way to do things (most of the time)

Comment: Thank-you :). I'm starting to see that, all guides and tutorials seem to use it.